# parse.com security concerns for android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have few questions regarding security

1. I am using sqlLite to sync data from parse to the android device.
   So is it safe to store the objectId of the rows in sqlLite tables
   because I may need them later to fetch data from server?
2. What if some hacker decompiles the apk, will he be able to retrieve
   the client_key and application_id, If yes, then how to
   secure these secret keys?

Comment: If the key is in your apk, a hacker can get them by disassembling.  If you want to secure them, send them to the device as needed over an encrypted channel, and require the user to provide some sort of authentication data (like a password) to prove he should have access.

Comment: i call Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY); inside onCreate method of a class that extends Application not Activity(as mentioned in Parse docs), so if i do auth of user before sending the credentials this class would have already been executed. How to call Parse.initialize after that ?